# WordPress: wp_query, meta_query array

Tags: php, arrays, get, wordpress

So I have 8 checkboxes: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H for example. All of them have the same name, and I need to get their values as an array in `meta_query`. I hope code can explain better than I do :)

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=>'paibcresume',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_query' => array(),
  'tax_query' => array(),
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'meta_key' => '',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);

// Search by occupation
//rbwwbusy - custom field
//rbseroccupation - search checkbox fields
if (isset($_GET['rbseroccupation']) && !empty($_GET['rbseroccupation'])) {
  $args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key'     => 'rbwwbusy',
    'value'   => array($_GET['rbseroccupation']),
    'compare' => 'IN'
  );
}

<div class="occupation">
  Occupation:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation" value="A">&nbsp;A
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation" value="B">&nbsp;B
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation" value="C">&nbsp;C
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation" value="D">&nbsp;D<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation" value="E">&nbsp;E
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation" value="F">&nbsp;F
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation" value="G">&nbsp;G
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation" value="H">&nbsp;H
</div>
```

So my question is: it works, but it only displays results for the last checked checkbox. So for example if i look for A and B, it only displays B; if I look for A, B and C it only display posts with C.

**What do I need to do, so it shows for example posts with A,B and C, not only the last checked?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the input names like this

```
<div class="occupation">
  Occupation:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation[]" value="A">&nbsp;A
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation[]" value="B">&nbsp;B
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation[]" value="C">&nbsp;C
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation[]" value="D">&nbsp;D<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation[]" value="E">&nbsp;E
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation[]" value="F">&nbsp;F
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation[]" value="G">&nbsp;G
  <input type="checkbox" name="rbseroccupation[]" value="H">&nbsp;H
</div>
```

The rest of the code should work fine.

Edit:
You should change this

```
 'value'   => array($_GET['rbseroccupation'])
```

to

```
 'value'   => $_GET['rbseroccupation']
```

or better to include the case where nothing is selected

```
 'value'   => (isset($_GET['rbseroccupation'])?$_GET['rbseroccupation']:array())
```

Because adding [] to input name makes it an array by deafult

Comment: Definitily missed that part, thank you very much! Maybe i shouldn't work that late at night :)